# Is there a way to toggle a boolean variable in C#?

Tags: c#, boolean

Is there a way to toggle the state of a Boolean variable in C#?

I'm aware that this is a simple solution:

```
bool locked = false;

if (locked == false)
{
    locked = true;
}
else
{
    locked = false;
}
```

But can it be done in one line in something like this:

```
bool locked = false

locked = locked.toggle();
```

Comment: FYI - You can use booleans in `if()` statments directly. Like `if(locked) { ... }` or `if(!locked && count>0) { ... }`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes. Use the following:

```
locked = !locked;
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Can that syntax be applied to any other variable types?

Comment: The `!` operator can be overloaded by other types, but it rarely is, because it doesn't often make intuitive sense to logically invert many types in a way that isn't better represented with an explicitly named method.

Comment: This! Sometimes I overlook the simplest, most elegant solution.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Imagin a `CustomColor : Color` class that overload the `!` operator to invert colors... 
`CustomColor color = Color.White; color = !color; //color now equal to Color.Black` ;)

Answer (score 14):

You could also do:

```
locked ^= true;
```

Comment: Why/how does it work? Explanation or link?

Comment: ^ is the exclusive or. "true ^ true" is false and "false ^ true" is true. So by doing "xyz ^ true", you invert the value of the left hand side. My line is a shorthand for "locked = locked ^ true;"

Comment: This should be the accepted answer !

Comment: @Elmue I disagree since 1) it's esoteric compared to `locked = !locked` and 2) it's easy to mistake for `locked = true` at a quick glance.

Comment: @MarredCheese In this ultra primitive sample you are right. But how do you toggle this? mi_Poly3DArr[k_Coord.X, k_Coord.Y].mi_Edit.mb_Selected ^= true;

Comment: @Elmue Ah, good point.  I'd prefer to avoid such complex expressions in the first place if possible though (e.g., `mi_Poly3DArr(k_Coord).ToggleEditSelection()`).

Answer (score 9):

You can define an extension method like this:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static bool Toggle(this bool value)
    {
        return !value;
    }
}
```

So that you can write something <s>more meaningful</s> like `locked = locked.Toggle()`

Hope it helps

Comment: "More meaningful" if you don't know the syntax of the language. This seems to me like needless complexity.

Comment: Sure, but just because you _can_ define an extension method doesn't mean you _should_. A C# programmer should know what the logical '!' operator does.

Comment: I totally agree, I just wanted to give an alternative answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following

```
locked = !locked;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think chomba's answer is great, an improvement can be made is using [ref parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#reference-return-values).

```
b.ToggleMe(); //b's value has changed. 
//b = b.ToggleMe(); // assign back to itself is not necessary. 

public static class UT
{
    public static bool ToggleMe (this ref bool b)
    {
        b=!b;     //toggle job is done.
        return b; //extra return value allows it being used inside expression.
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Always throws ![CS0206](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0206?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0206)) with `ref`.
So that doesnt work!